# How to apply separate_rows() to all columns, passing a `sep` parameter?

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

Pretty straight straightforward: I have a data frame where the values in many columns need to be split into their own rows, based on `;`s as the delimiter.

After reading a bit,

```
df %>%
   Reduce(separate_rows_, x = colnames)
```

works, except that I can't pass the `sep` parameter (so it also separates by white spaces, commas, and other non-alphanumeric chars).

One answer proposed writing a modified version of the function that includes the parameter, but I couldn't get that working:

`Reduce(f = function(y) separate_rows_(sep = ";"), x = colnames)`

What am I doing wrong?

Having said that, my ideal solution would be a tidyverse solution, if it's cleaner (maybe `map_dfr`?); but obviously any solution is better than none :).

Here's sample data:

```
structure(list(q1 = c("1,2,3,4", "2,4"), q2 = c("a,b", "e,f"), 
q3 = c("c,d", "g,h,z")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
structure(list(q1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), q2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "e", 
"e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f"), q3 = c("c", 
"d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "d", 
"c", "d", "g", "h", "z", "g", "h", "z", "g", "h", "z", "g", "h", 
"z")), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

The process I want to streamline is not having to pass every column name like so:

```
output <- test %>% 
  separate_rows(q1, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate_rows(q2, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate_rows(q3, sep = ",")
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: Ok, give me a few mins.

Comment: If you are using `tidyverse`, then try  `df %>% reduce(separate_rows_, sep=";")`

Comment: I tried that and got `Error in UseMethod("separate_rows_") : no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object of class "character"`. Anyway, I'll be afk for a bit—thanks for the help so far.

Comment: `reduce(.init = df, .x = names(df), .f = ~separate_rows(.x, {{.y}}, sep = ','))` should work, modifying akrun's idea

Comment: Or similar to IceCreamToucan suggested, with `base R` `Reduce(function(x, y) separate_rows(x, y, sep=","), names(test), init = test)`

Comment: Actually, it is your answer.  I tried with `reduce` earlier, but couldn't fix.  Please do post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::reduce`, which applies the given function `.f` to `.init` and the first element of `.x`, then applies the function to the output of that and the second element of `.x`, etc. until all elements of `.x` have been used.

Within the `.f` argument formula, `.x` is the previous output (or `.init` for the first run) and `.y` is the given element of the `.x` argument to `reduce`.

```
library(tidyverse)

reduce(.init = df, .x = names(df), .f = ~separate_rows(.x, .y, sep = ','))
# equiv to: reduce(.init = df, .x = names(df), .f = separate_rows, sep = ',')
```

As akrun notes in the comments, this can also be done in base R with the code below (same output)

```
Reduce(function(x, y) separate_rows(x, y, sep=","), names(df), init = df)

#    q1 q2 q3
# 1   1  a  c
# 2   1  a  d
# 3   1  b  c
# 4   1  b  d
# 5   2  a  c
# 6   2  a  d
# 7   2  b  c
# 8   2  b  d
# 9   3  a  c
# 10  3  a  d
# 11  3  b  c
# 12  3  b  d
# 13  4  a  c
# 14  4  a  d
# 15  4  b  c
# 16  4  b  d
# 17  2  e  g
# 18  2  e  h
# 19  2  e  z
# 20  2  f  g
# 21  2  f  h
# 22  2  f  z
# 23  4  e  g
# 24  4  e  h
# 25  4  e  z
# 26  4  f  g
# 27  4  f  h
# 28  4  f  z
```

Comment: You can also add the `Reduce`